# Здравствуйте. Не понимаю как решить задачу со структурами в си

Tags: c, структуры, текстовые-файлы

Описать структуру сотрудник: Фамилия Имя Отчество, должность, стаж, зарплата, дата рождения. Определить сотрудников, имеющих

- зарплату выше средней,
- возраст менее N лет.

Предусмотреть повышение зарплаты для тех, стаж которых больше k лет.

Нужно считать данные из текстового файла.

Структура:

```
struct worker {
char name[50];
char work[20];
int time;
int pay;
int born;
```

};

Comment: Что именно вам непонятно? что такое структура - можно [тут](https://learnc.info/c/structures.html) прочесть.

Comment: как реализовать ввод данных с текстового документа именно в этой задаче

Comment: Не вижу в задаче "чтение из текстового файла", могу предположить его наличие, но вы уточните таки, слово **текстовый** точно имеется? потому что в таких случаях принято использовать бинарные форматы. Давайте мы поступим по правилам данного сайта, вы опишите структуру, добавите саму структуру в вопрос, и я вам подскажу как читать и записывать бинарные данные в си :)

Comment: Всё  изменил !))

Comment: https://metanit.com/cpp/c/7.3.php а вот и чтение подъехало :) с записью вместе :)

Comment: Как заполнить структуру с клавиатуры вы понимаете?

Comment: спасибо большое !)

Comment: да как заполнить с клавиатуры понимаю

Comment: Вам дали плохой совет. Там пишется неинициализированная память, а файл который получится не будет текстовым. Так не нужно делать.

Comment: Если вы умеете считать с клавиатуры, то сумеете те ми же операциями прочитать из текстового файла.

Comment: блин что-то я запутался. А не подскажете пожалуйста как прочитать из текстового теми же операциями что и с клавиатуры

Comment: `scanf` -> `fscanf`.